# How to write tests in android studio and how to deal with them

Tags: android, testing, software-quality

I have been developing apps in android studio for around 2 years and i know that each developer can write tests but i have never done it before.

I read what is documented on the official [developer.android](http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)  website but i didn`t received the results i want on how to deal with tests i only learned type of tests but not really when to use each one and not how to write and run a test.

I didn`t get the big picture yet in writing tests and also how to write a test so please and guidance.

Comment: Your question is very vague, and it's not clear what kind of answers you expect.

Comment: I expect some procedures of somebody who is experienced in writing tests in android